# Create a column with date which is 3 years in the past from the given date column (pyspark)?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a column using pyspark that contains the date which is 3 years prior to the date in a given column. The date column looks like this :

```
             date        
        2018-08-01   
        2016-08-11
        2014-09-18
        2018-12-08
        2011-12-18
```

And I want this result :

```
         date         past date
        2018-08-01   2015-08-01
        2016-08-11   2013-08-11
        2014-09-18   2011-09-18
        2018-12-08   2015-12-08
        2011-12-18   2008-12-18
```

Comment: using time interval : `df.withColumn("past_date", to_date(expr("date - interval 3 year")))`

Comment: @Faliha Zikra, Not sure how would **`accepted answer`** addresses leap year? if we are **`subtracting based on days`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_sub` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html).

Here is Scala code which will be very to python.

`df.withColumn("past_date",date_sub(col("date"), 1095))`

Answer (score 1):

Try with [**`add_months`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.add_months) function in pyspark and multiply `12` with `-3`!

**`Example:`**

```
l = l=[('2018-08-01',),('2016-08-11',)]
ll=["date"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(l,ll)
df.withColumn("past_date",add_months(col("`date`"),-3*12)).show()
```

**`RESULT:`**

```
+----------+----------+
|      date| past_date|
+----------+----------+
|2018-08-01|2015-08-01|
|2016-08-11|2013-08-11|
+----------+----------+
```